# mysql truncate table on boot

Tags: mysql, truncate

```
How to truncate MySQL table on boot,
but want make sure script execute after mysqld started

mysql -h localhost -u root -pPASSWORD DBNAME -e "truncate table tables"
```

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a script startup.sql, store it in your data directory, make it readable to the server. The startup.sql script contains the statements you need, for example "TRUNCATE TABLE tables;".

Add the following line to the [mysqld] section of your my.cnf file:

init-file=startup.sql

Stop and restart the server to test.

The relevant documentation can be found here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_init-file

Answer (score 0):

depends on why you need it truncating...

perhaps consider using a memory table which would be 'truncated' on server restart anyway as it is only held in memory...

otherwise yoou coud add a line to truncate each table you need truncating to the set-up script and ensure that the script is called on startup.

Comment: In my purpose, because in mysql table relate to iptables rules, it will not create new iptables rule if exist in mysql table. So how start up script look like?

Comment: put all your truncate statements in a text file (makes sure you specify schema.table otherwise it will break something). on the box find the command that is run to start mysql and add --defaults-file="path/to/your/file.txt" if this is already set then I'd suggest you add your statements to this file.